# How to control frame rate in html5 canvas in " for loop" controlled draw function

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making use of HTML5 canvas for visual representation of selection sorting. I made seperate draw function and placed it inside the outer for-loop ,intended to update screen after every number swaping.
On running the code it just shows the final result in one shot.

***THE CODE***:-

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
var height = 400;
var width = 400;

canvas.height = height;
canvas.width = width;

const c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var arr = [];

for(var i=0;i<width/3;i++){
    arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
}

var len = arr.length;
function show(){
    c.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(3*i,height);
        c.lineTo(3*i,arr[i]);
        c.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
        c.stroke();
    }
}


var temp;
var index;


for(var i = 0;i < len;i++){
    index = i;
    for(var j = i;j < len;j++){
        if(arr[j] >= arr[index]){
            index = j;
        }
    }
    temp = arr[index];
    arr[index] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = temp;
    show();
}
```

I tried using a for-loop to make a time buffer, but that also fails.
I tried using requestAnimationFrame with some code patches to control framerate , but then the sorting might fail

So, what is the way to control framerate in HTML5 canvas with for-loop controlled draw/update funtion?

Comment: Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: @WaisKamal after using it along show in the inner for-loop the dispaly waits work 3000 millisec and displayed sorted list , i want to see one by one

Comment: You seem to be talking about `setTimeout`, which executes a code block after a given time, as opposed to `setInterval`, which **continuously** executes a code block at specified intervals.